# Linear Map Adjoint or Inverse?

Tags: adjoint-operators

In my lecture notes, we have a linear map $\mathcal{A}(X)=X_{11}$ that maps $X\in S^2$ to its first element. It then claims that $\mathcal{A}^*(X_{11})=
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{11}&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}$ is the adjoint.

To me I understand it by $\mathcal{A}(X)=
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}
X
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
=X_{11}$
, so we solve for $X$:
$$
\begin{align}
X&=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\Bigg(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}
X
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\Bigg)
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
X_{11}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\mathcal{A}^*(X_{11}).
\end{align}$$

However, (coming from a physics background) this seems like we found the inverse $\mathcal{A}^{-1}$, not $\mathcal{A}^*$ the adjoint. From what I know (from physics), the adjoint of an operator is its (conjugate) transpose, which we would have derived by doing:
$$\mathcal{A}^*(X_{11})=
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}^T
X_{11}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}^T
=
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
X_{11}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Is either of these the correct way? I'm guessing it's probably the latter, and that here we happen to have $\mathcal{A}^*=\mathcal{A}^{-1}$, but I'm confused because I've never seen this done before, and I've also never seen a map/operator not represented just by a single matrix.

Comment: The linear map is defined on vector space. In particular, if we choose orthonormal bases of both spaces, one can show that the matrix representations of $L^∗$ and $L$ are related by $[L^∗]=[L]^T$. You can read more about it here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769834/definition-of-adjoint-of-a-linear-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the correct way to derive the answer. It is important to note (and something I forgot to mention above) that we are working with a trace inner product. We derive $\mathcal{A}^*$ as follows:

$$
\DeclareMathOperator{Tr}{Tr}
\langle y,\mathcal{A}(X)\rangle
=\langle \mathcal{A}^*(y),X\rangle
=yX_{11}
=\Tr\big(\mathcal{A}^*(y)X\big)
=\sum_{i,j} \big(\mathcal{A}^*(y)\big)_{ij}X_{ij}
$$
Thus for a general $X\in S^2$, we must have that $\mathcal{A}^*(y)=\begin{bmatrix}y&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$

I'm not $100$% certain about the other two ways I proposed, but this is the way to derive $\mathcal{A}^*$ in general.